# Oracle SQL Update passed as parameter (into stored procedure) string from .NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, oracle, sql-update

I would like to know how to accomplish this task. I've looked at CASE, DECODE or IF condition and I'm not able to make it work. My goal is to pass a block of predefined column/value pair constructed from ASP.NET data to my Oracle stored procedure. I am trying to only update certain columns out of many to preserve other columns not needing updates. So here's my set up:

Stored procedure:

```
UpdateSelectedColumns(myValuePairString, updatedBy)

-- Passed variable from ASP.NET, myValuePairString = 'col1 = 10,col2 = 'Dog''

-- update statement final
UPDATE MyTable   
       SET
       col1 = 10,
       col2 = 'Dog'
       col3 = 'john';
COMMIT;
```

Thank you in advance...

Ricky

Answer (score 1):

For once I'm gonna advise to not use a stored proc. There is no point here in using a stored procedure.

As it is your stored procedure would blindly accept its arguments and execute the update without adding any value. Furthermore, by using this procedure, you preclude the use of binds and exposes yourself to bugs (whenever you encouner a value with a quote `'`), performance hit and SQL injection vulnerability.

The advantage of PL/SQL (simple transparent binding, transparent use and reuse of cursors, strict static SQL parsing and metadata dependancy) are all pointless if you take an aribtrary string as argument and put it in a dynamic cursor.

You'll be better off to use your language native cursors and use bind variables.

If you really want to use PL/SQL, replace your single argument with a couple of tables. One for the column names, one for the variable values. You could then use [`DBMS_SQL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sql.htm#BABEDAHF) to parse the statement and use appropriate bind variables. You'll need some convention to be able to parse date, number and character values. You'll need to read metadata from the database to check the datatypes. This would be a lot of code for not a bit of value.